# How to set a timeout to shell commands executed with PHP in Windows

Tags: php, shell, timeout, exec

I'm using **passthru($command)** to execute a imagemagick converting command.

Simply speaking, if this shell command itself got stuck owing to some unexplainable reasons, thus passthru() was also stuck. How to set a timeout limit to this passthru code, such as 2 min? I suppose to get a return value in order to do wrong case processing, not **set_time_limit()**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:

### PHP shell_exec with a timeout

This function allows you to execute another process but with a timeout on how long it’s allowed to run.

> http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/08/24/execute-with-timeout.html